# Input type text same format as date

Tags: html, date, text, input

My question is, if it is possible that my input type text has the same format as a input type date. The date type actually looks almost the same but it has'-' in the textbox by default and you can't remove them, that is exactly what I want.

I hope you guys get it and can help me !

If it is impossible please let me know, so I stop hoping.

I need something like `sharepoint/company/subcompany` and slashes should be non-removable in the input field

Comment: example text you want to enter in that field ?

Comment: 'sharepoint/company/subcompany', so I want to have the '/' as default.

Comment: so after entering the first value. you yourself will go to next slash and enter the content  and so on right ?

Comment: Yes exactly that! :)

Comment: you can use jquery mask ? is it ok for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the mask plugin from below link:

[**https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/**](https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SCzVP/745/)

html:

```
<input id="product" type="text" tabindex="7" />
```

**jquery:**

```
jQuery(function($) {   
    $("#product").mask("aaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaa");
});
```

Comment: Seriously thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted <3

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using HTML5, try this - it also adds a date picker:

```
<input type="date" value="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

If you want to do this using a normal `type="text"` input then you'll have to write a javascript solution

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I'm trying is to have a input type text with the format like this 'sharepoint/company/subcompany' and I want to have the '/' as default so you can't remove them exactly as the input type date.

Comment: Why not use the above then? It does exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: I can still remove the '-', I want it non-removable

Answer (score 0):

this should work. If HTML5 is ok. i think this code will not work on internet explorer

```
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I'm trying is to have a input type text with the format like this 'sharepoint/company/subcompany' and I want to have the '/' as default so you can't remove them exactly as the input type date.